# Mobile network provider blocking volley requests to the api

Tags: android, android-volley

I am calling TMDb API from volley but my network provider is blocking the request for some reason. The logcat shows:

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "api.themoviedb.org": No address associated with hostname
```

I don't know how to proceed further on with this issue.

Comment: How do you know it is from the network provider? Did you try on a different network provider?

Comment: Well just check it with wifi see if works?

Comment: Yes. I tried with other networks and it works.

Comment: @AmitParameshwar Did you found the answer ? I am facing similar type of issue.

Comment: @Codelover it seems that Airtel India network (my current network) has blocked the url. Can't help it. But you can use [1.1.1.1](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloudflare.onedotonedotonedotone&hl=en_IN) to bypass that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the internet permission enabled in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: Yes it is enabled